Is a ledger board necessary when tiling above a tub?
Tiling a three-walled tub alcove using 4” x 4” porcelain tiles (motif) on the back wall, and 4” x 12” vertical subway on the side walls.  The 4x4 tiles are especially “hand made” meaning they vary in size by about 1/8”.   My tub deck of course drops by about 1/8” from end to end with about a 1/16” dip in the middle.  Would wedged spacers along with some minor tile cutting accomplish the same straight line atop my bottom row that a ledger board would? My hesitation in using a ledger board is simply that I cannot find six feet of 1” x 2” wood that is straight.  Not sure how it is on the Mainland, but here in Hawaii, unless you’re paying for finished wood for shelves, etc., 1x2s are almost always more wavy that my tub deck.

6' and straight.
If you're careful a chalk line may be enough,  or use the factory edge of an off-cut from a manufactured panel (mdf/plywood/osb/drywall/whatever)
or buy an old shelf, ( door, whatever )  from a building recycler.

I’ve got a laser level on the wall, so no problem seeing my goal.  Great tip on the building recycler.  There is one downtown who should have something factory edged.

It seems that being the tiles you are using are not uniform in size, there is no reason to worry about having a straight line to begin with.
Just use the tub edge and adjust with spacers to get the tops as level as possible. The next row will vary slightly because of the difference in tile size, but it will give an appearance of being straight and level.
Remember even with close to perfect lines between tiles, there is sometimes an uneven look. When grouted, this all goes away.  Don't fret so much about it, the grout will bring everything together.

Great point about the grout.  My wife wants me to do 1/16” spacers but I”m thinking 1/8” because of the tiles’ lack of uniformity.  Thoughts?

Because tiles are not uniform, you will end up with non uniform grout lines.  (Your wife and you will both get what you want.) Believe me it will be impossible to arrange a uniform grout line throughout the entire wall.  My advice, embrace the perfectly imperfect size of the grout lines.
